# Firestore NoSql Following and Followers system

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, nosql

Suppose the tipical web where a user has followers and also follows other users. I am trying to make a good database structure for this. Until now, I was doing this:

```
/
---users (collection)
|---------- userId (document)
|          |-------------- document data
|---------- user1Id (document)
           |-------------- document data
            ...

---following
|---------- userId (document)
|          |---------------- users (collection) <--------- The users that userId follows
|                            | ----------- user1Id (document)
|                            | ----------- user2Id (document)
|---------- user1Id (document)
           |--------------- users (collection) 
                             | ----------- user2Id (document)
                             | ----------- user3Id (document)
```

With this database structure, I am able to store an infinite number of users in the following collection, and successfully see each user that an user is currently following. The problem comes when I want to see the follwers of an user. I am doubtful wheter to create another collection "userFollowers" inside all the "userId" documents in my "following" collection which represents the followers of an specific user, I mean, in the same level as the "users" collection which is contained in "following", or if it would be better not to do so and create it at the same level as "following".

I don't know, I am new in Firestore and in NoSQL databases, is this a common way to solve this or is there a better option?

Comment: If they both can be queried in a way that meets the needs of your app, then it's simply a matter of preference.

Comment: If I retrieve the document "userId1" from the following collection, will I be getting both collections "users" (I will rename this to "usersFollowing") and "usersFollowers"? That is why I am not sure if this is a good option, as I was thinking of retrieving a collection when a user is in the "Following screen" and the other when he is in the "Followers screen"

Comment: Okey I am stupid, I think I can do db.collection("following").document().collection().get() sorry! And thanks a lot man for your feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to have a answer for this question...

As @conchi-bermejo mentioned above, a solution for this can be using `db.collection("following").document(userId).collection().get()`

Also as this [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#list_subcollections_of_a_document) mentions, this another way to get those documents:

```js
collections = db.collection("following").document(userId).collections()
for collection in collections:
    for doc in collection.stream():
        print(f'{doc.id} => {doc.to_dict()}')
```

Just as a tip, the docs are your best friends when getting started c:

Comment: Hello thank you! Also, do you know why is there a -1 and a 0 in your answer? I marked this as a good answer

Comment: Those are the votes for a question, comment or answer. You can learn more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)